# Embed a mesh onto another

Tags: modeling

[image: If I just place the stairs, they are too high (left)]I would like to embed the stairs mesh in the picture onto the bridge mesh. I tried shrinkwrap but it didn't work as I wished. The bridge should recede like dough when the stairs are pressed onto it. In Shrinkwrap, the bridge behaves rather like water. My experience with Blender does not exceed two weeks' time, so any help would be valuable!

[image]

Comment: Unless you are animating it, can't you just place it on the bridge manually?

Comment: Can you clarify what "embed" means in this context?

Comment: I tried placing it, but the stairs are either too high or too low. Thank you, however

Comment: Carlo, with "embed" I mean using the stairs to push the upper surface of the bridge, so they can replace the bridge's surface.

Comment: Try using a boolean modifier set to "union".

Comment: maybe you should extrude down your stairs so that it has thickness then put it on the bridge. If you need to join to the bridge, use Boolean.